# How to Display NSSet value in UItableView Using NSmutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsset

I'm having an array of elements like this

150,
150,
150,
571,
571,
571,
692,
692,
692,
123,
123,
123,
144,
144,
144,
147,
147,
147,
155,
155,
155,
542,
542,
542,
548,
548,
548,
551,
551,
551

I used to display my array elements in tableviewcell where i used code like this

```
NSArray *array=[jsonarray valueForKey:@"ID"];
mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:array] ;

NSLog(@"%@",mySet);
```

now i got my all elements which is not repeated as 11 elements in myset but if i printed myset value i got like this

2012-08-01 12:49:53.049 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.050 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.050 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.051 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.051 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.052 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.052 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.053 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.053 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.054 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}
2012-08-01 12:49:53.054 jothi R&D[3647:f803] {(
    551,
    548,
    692,
    150,
    155,
    147,
    542,
    571,
    123,
    144
)}

and if i tried to print that in UItableviewcell i got BAD ACCESS issue at return[myset count];.My table view cell contains

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return  [myset count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


{        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



}
// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.text=[myset objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    

return cell;
}
```

Here jsonarray is NSMutableArray,myset is NSSet..Guidance please..

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the NSSet does not accept duplicates, so you 'have more elements in your NSMutablearray

so you must chose to use one of them in all you dataSource methodes